# Mi aplicacion Yii2 no funciona bien cuando la subo al servidor

Tags: yii2

Sucede que cuando subi mi aplicacion Yii2 al servidor solo me abre bien la pagina de inicio, cuando quiero acceder a las demas páginas, me muestra un error de que la pagina solicitada no existe

Uso URLs amigables, que funcionan bien en localhost, en mi PC donde la estoy diseñando

¿Que hay que configurar en el servidor para que funcione bien la aplicacion con urls amigables?
O donde hay que buscar la causa del problema?

Nota: Puedo administrar el servidor web, asi que cualquier configuracion la puedo hacer

Comment: subiste el htacess? como lo tienes?

Comment: Pues si, lo subi y este es su contenido     <codigo> IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

Comment: Revisa que en el confi.php esté habilitada, que tu .htaccess este en la misma ruta que la ruta de inicio y que tu index también esté ahí

Comment: El .htacess y el index.php estan juntos en la raiz del sitio, en la carpeta web de la plantilla de Yii2 y en el config.php esta esto:    'urlManager' => [       
                        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
                        'showScriptName' => false,  // Disable index.php
                        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,  // Disable r= routes
                        'rules' => [
                                     'contrato/index/<estado>' => 'contrato/index',
                        ],
        ],

Comment: Intenta poniendo tu index.php afuera del web, es decir realmente en la raiz y tu .htaccess también, puede que tu server esté apuntando a el directorio en general y no a la carpeta web

Comment: Hice lo que me indicaste, pero de esa forma no funciona nada

Comment: Regresa los archivos a donde estaban y verifica si tienes activo el rewrite en apache

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Answer (score 0):

Pues ya encontre la solucion, activando el modo rewrite en el apache

Cambiar **AllowOverride none** por **AllowOverride All**

muchas gracias Sr1871 por la ayuda

Comment: Vaya, que pense q estaba resuelto todo, ahora en algunas paginas me da este error: Class yii\i18n\formatter does not exist

Comment: Eliminando la referencia a esa clase, funciona todo bien, la estaba usando para los formatos de numeros, pero veo que sin eso tambien funciona, porque parece que lo toma de la configuracion regional de la PC

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes href similares con la palabra index.php  debes eliminar la parte que dice index.php ejemplo

href='index.php?r=radicados'

debes corregirlo asi

href='?r=radicados'

y a todo funcionará correctamente

Comment: Ya solucione el problema, como ya habia acomentado anteriormente, eran en la configuraciuon del apache. Ademas, uso url amigables. Igual muchas gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Referente al error del formatter que comentaba (Class yii\i18n\formatter does not exist). El problema es que linux es case sensitive con los nombres, la solucion fue cambiar la referencia de la clase de formatter por Formatter, con inicial mayuscula